# AUC for more than two groups?

Tags: classification, ordinal-data, roc, auc

Standard ROC curves look at how setting various thresholds on a continuous measure can be used to predict a two-level ordinal outcome (example: antibody level -> (not sick, sick) ). This can then be integrated over the whole range of thresholds yielding the classical Area Under the Curve (AUC).

**The AUC has an interesting alternative definition**: it is also the probability that, for a given pair of subjects, the continuous measure will rank them correctly with respect to the ordinal outcome.

In the case where this ordinal outcome has more than two levels (example: not sick, a little sick, very sick) , this alternative definition can be used to get a **natural generalization of the concept of AUC.**

My question is: **does this generalization have a name**? Is it a standard or at least known measure? **Are there any more widely used alternatives?**

Comment: This paper : http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A%3A1010920819831#page-1 has a very similar approach, but considers the case where the output classes are not ordered and thus gives a different expression.

Answer (score 4):

I'm no expert, but I have recently read a paper exploring some of the AUC extensions to multiclass.  They called their extension **Volume Under the ROC Surface** and they also explored some other extension options.  Here's a direct link to the work of Ferri et al:

[Volume Under the ROC Surface for Multi-class Problems](http://users.dsic.upv.es/grupos/elp/cferri/vus-ecml03-camera-ready4.pdf)

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem they tackle is a bit different (and more complicated), since they seem to assume any classifiers working on any inputs, whereas I use the original ROC curve with a single scalar input and the trivial threshold classifiers. Good finding anyways, thanks!